# Stop jquery tabs from moving to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set up tabs on a site using jquery, so that 4 pages of data can be shown without refreshing the page. 
[image]

This works fine but there is one quirk which I want rid of! If ive scrolled down the first page a bit, and then click on another tab, the 2nd tab appears but is no longer scrolled down (ie it appears and the page moves back up to the top). This makes the page 'look' as though its reloading even though its not. Is there a way to prevent the page moving, ie locking the scrollbar in its current position?

This is the script for creating the tabs and loading the different sections into view:

```
<script>
//add the tabs
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.panel').hide();
    $('.tabs a.active').removeClass('active');
    $this.addClass('active').blur();
    var panel = $this.attr('href');
    $(panel).fadeIn(250);
    return false;
    }); //end click
$('.tabs li:first a').click();
}); //end ready
</script>
```

Comment: Need to see your output how about making fiddle???

Comment: Its ok, solution below works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/):

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thats the one! superb!

Comment: Ive just posted another separate question if you want another accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use event.preventDefault(); You can restrict the default behavior using this function and code accordingly to your requirement.

```
$( ".tabs a" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});
```